# Typescript nested index type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a type level function `Foo` which will get the types of the first elements of a "two dimensional" array. I have written the following

```
type Foo<A extends any[][]> = {
    [I in keyof A]: First<A[I]>
}

type First<A extends any[]> = A[0]
```

This code does not compile with the following error

```
Type 'A[I]' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'.
  Type 'A[keyof A]' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
    Type 'A[string] | A[number] | A[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
      Type 'A[string]' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
```

which I am struggling to understand. Specifically, where `A[string] | A[number] | A[symbol]` comes from. It is my understanding that [mapped arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) should allow me to index the elements of the array which should be more arrays. I can work around this issue with conditional types by defining `First` like so

```
type First<A> =
    A extends any[] ? A[0] :
    never;
```

but I do not understand why this is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty obnoxious, I know.  It is marked as a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  The underlying issue [seems to be](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995#issuecomment-433056847) that the compiler only realizes it's mapping an array/tuple when you *use* the mapped type, not when you *define* it.

```
// here the compiler doesn't know that I will be a numeric-like key:
type Foo<A extends any[][]> = { [I in keyof A]: Extract<A[I], any[]>[0] };

// only here does the compiler perform the mapping with just the numeric-like keys:
type Expected = Foo<[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]>;
// type Expected = [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

It also turns out that it's possible to make the compiler map an array type as a plain object, including those non-numeric-like keys such as `length`, `join`, etc.:

```
type Unexpected = Foo<[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] & { a: string }>;
/* type Unexpected = {
    [x: number]: 1 | 3 | 5 | 7;
    0: 1;
    1: 3;
    2: 5;
    3: 7;
    length: never;
    toString: never;
    toLocaleString: never;
    pop: never;
    push: never;
    concat: never;
    join: never;
    reverse: never;
    shift: never;
    slice: never;
    sort: never;
    ... 18 more ...;
    a: never;
}
*/
```

The fact that this is even possible means that the compiler can't assume that `A[I]` is assignable to `any[]`, so you're currently stuck with having to do something like `Extract<A[I], any[]>` (which is similar to your fix).

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the link to the ticket and the `Extract` suggestion.